# How I can fix the "The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it." Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have 2 monsters and 1 player. when players shoot, i get this mistake and they stop shooting. I have the same code for players, but players can keep shooting. I think the problem is with "destroy" but I can not find a solution [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLgkH.png)

```
    public class SpawnBulletController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bullet;
    public float interval = 1F;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        
            InvokeRepeating("ShootBullet", interval, interval);
        
        
    }

    void ShootBullet()
    {
        GameObject g = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        
    }
    

}

    public class BorderCollision : MonoBehaviour
{

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        
        if (other.gameObject.tag != "Player")
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's multiple problems and it's difficult to narrow down what exactly is causing your error but yes, it's likely caused by the fact that you're destroying the 'other' when a collision happens. You are using 2 classes in one script and Unity might change behaviour depending on the name of the script in this case.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO - you're in the right place and you'll grow to realise what an incredible resource the StackOverflow community is. To help us help you, it's always a good idea to supply a stack trace, an exact error message, what triggered the error and enough code to allow community members to see what happened before and during the problem code block. Often, explaining the issue can help you see the solution better too. Good luck and welcome again! (P.S. - your bullet field value is null when you call Instantiate and g is destroyed when ShootBullet returns...)

Comment: Please verify which object you have referenced in `bullet`.

The error message comes from `Instantiate` and in the moment the error is thrown the `bullet` was destroyed already.

Comment: @MarkGreen `g` is not "detroyed" when the method ends (a bit misleading formulation in the context of Unity) only the variable holding the reference does not exist anymore but the instantiated object ofcourse will not be destroyed ;)

Answer (score 0):

When your **collider** hits any **GameObject** that has no "Player" tag the **GameObject** will be destroyed this is wrong.

you should try

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collider)
{
    
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Monster")
        Destroy(collider.gameObject);
}
```

And if you want to destroy more with the same code but not with the same tag you should try.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collider)
{
    
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Monster" || collider.gameObject.tag == "Monster2")
        Destroy(collider.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't work because I have deleted "if" code but still I get the same errors :(

Comment: in general you should rather use `gameObject.CompareTag("tag")` instead of `==` ... the first throws an exception in case of typos or non-existent tags .. the latter simply fails silently making you debugging live a nightmare ;)

Comment: @Nick why is it wrong? Maybe it is supposed to only be destroyed when not hitting a player? ;)